# Create disposable object via factory in Using statement

Tags: vb.net, factory, using-statement

Assume base class Foo implements IDisposable. Classes `FooA` and `FooB` inherit class Foo. A simple factory method, `FooFactory.Create()` returns either a FooA or FooB object depending on the needs of the client.

In the client code below (FooTest module), attempting to use the factory method in a 'Using' statement results in the following compile error:

**'Using' resource variable must have an explicit initialization.**

I'd appreciate any suggestions (best practices) regarding an implementation that would support the instantiation of FooA or FooB (specified by client) via the Using statement. A Factory isn't required - it's simply the approach I tried. Ideally, I'd like FooA and FooB to be separate classes with a common base class or interface.

Thanks in advance for any help you might provide.

```
Public Module FooTest

    Public Sub Test()
        'the following compiles:
        Dim f As Foo = FooFactory.Create("A")
        f.DoWork()
        f.Dispose()
        'the following causes a compile error:
        ''Using' resource variable must have an explicit initialization.
        Using f As FooFactory.Create("A")
            f.DoWork()
        End Using
    End Sub

End Module

Public Module FooFactory

    Public Function Create(ByVal AorB As String) As Foo
        If AorB = "A" Then
            Return New FooA
        Else
            Return New FooB
        End If
    End Function

    Public Class FooA : Inherits Foo
    End Class

    Public Class FooB : Inherits Foo
    End Class

    Public MustInherit Class Foo : Implements IDisposable
        Public Overridable Sub DoWork()
        End Sub
        Public Overridable Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose
        End Sub
    End Class

End Module
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just have the syntax wrong on the Using line.  Write it just like the Dim, replacing Dim with Using:

```
Using f As Foo = FooFactory.Create("A")
```

You can't say "As FooFactory.Create" since a type must follow the "As" keyword.

Comment: Ugh. Thanks Stuart. ...and apologies to anyone who wasted time on this post.